# Escaping alias commands in a gitconfig files

Tags: git, git-config

I'm trying to add an alias command to my gitconfig file and it reports "bad config file" on the line I've added. I suspect it's something to do with the `sed` command and some escaping issues, but I don't know exactly what it's supposed to be. Here's the command, with linebreaks added for legibility:

```
impact = !git ls-files -z
       | xargs -0n1 git blame -w -C
       | sed -r 's/^[^(]+\((.*) [0-9]{4}-.*/\1/'
       | sed -r 's/ +$//'
       | sort -f
       | uniq -c
       | sort -nr
```

Comment: Why don't you put that code into a shell script?

Comment: yeah I thought about that, but it feels a lot neater to call it as `git impact`... I guess I could put it into a shell script and then add an alias to the script...

Comment: @nickf I confirm your alias does work (without any shell script wrapper)

Comment: If you put in a script called `git-impact`, git will call it if you execute `git impact`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect it is more about the '`\`', which needs to be doubled.

I tried your alias with '`\\`' without any error message.

```
impact = !git ls-files -z
       | xargs -0n1 git blame -w -C
       | sed -r 's/^[^(]+\\((.*) [0-9]{4}-.*/\\1/'
       | sed -r 's/ +$//'
       | sort -f
       | uniq -c
       | sort -nr
```